# When is the induced map $f^{*}:\operatorname{Spec}(S) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, covering-spaces, affine-schemes

Let $f: R \to S$ be a ring homomorphism. When is the induced map $f^{*}: \operatorname{Spec}(S) \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ on topological spaces a covering map?

More precisely, are there any interesting necessary or sufficient (algebraic) conditions on $f$ for $f^*$ to be a covering map? Note that obviously a covering map is surjective, so every prime ideal of $R$ must be a contracted ideal.

I would also appreciate it if someone could only explain example of covering spaces in this setting.
On [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Covering_space) one can find the assertion

> The map of affine schemes ${\text{Spec}}(\mathbb {C}[x,t,t^{-1}]/(x^{n}-t))\to {\text{Spec}}(\mathbb {C} [t,t^{-1}])$ forms a covering space with $\mathbb {Z} /n$ as its group of deck transformations.

But I cannot see why this true. Perhaps someone could start by examining this example.

Comment: That example on Wikipedia is incorrect, if you are taking "covering map" in the usual topological sense.  Rather, it is an example of a map which has properties analogous to covering maps, but in the setting of algebraic geometry.  I don't know of any natural interesting maps of covering maps (in the topological sense) between schemes.

Comment: It is correct if Spec is interpreted to mean $\mathbb{C}$-points with the analytic topology.

Comment: The maps Eric's referencing that have properties analogous to covering maps are called étale maps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_morphism). Galois theory for them is controlled by a group called the étale fundamental group (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tale_fundamental_group).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's not quite right; étale maps correspond to local homeomorphisms, not covering maps.  Covering maps correspond to _finite_ étale maps.